# exec-maven-plugin how to exit SQL*Plus

Tags: maven, exec, sqlplus

I'm using the `exec-maven-plugin` to run SQL script (simple DML), then I run:

```
mvn clean install -Prunmysql
```

and during execution I get `SQL>` console opened and can't proceed until manually type `EXIT`.

How can I  let the plugin know, that it needs to exit SQL console after execution?

```
<profile>
  <id>runmysql</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <executable>sqlplus</executable>
              <arguments>
                <argument>user/pwd@localhost:1521/dbname</argument>
                <argument>@myfile.sql</argument>
              </arguments>
              <workingDirectory>C:\sqlproject\</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: You can try and execute `mvn clean install -Prunmysql && exit` as a single command

Comment: did you check [this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/87035/run-oracle-sql-script-and-exit-from-sqlplus-exe-via-command-prompt)?